# Como cambiar contenido de div haciendo click en un botón

Tags: javascript, html5, wordpress

Estoy trabajando en un portal con wordpress y necesito ayuda para conseguir cambiar el contenido de un **DIV**, al hacer click en un botón que está dentro de **OTRO DIV**.

Para detallar mejor, les dejo el código de mi ***HEADER.php*** donde quiero que se modifique el contenido..

```css
header {
 height: 100vh;
 background-position:center;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("https://k32.kn3.net/taringa/1/1/6/0/7/6/3/johannlukas/3C8.jpg?4292");
}

#sticky {
 position: absolute;
 margin: 0 auto;
 left: 5%;
 right: 5%;
 bottom: 5%;
}

#sticky .btn {
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: 900;
 background-color: #25c481;
 line-height: normal;
 padding: 8px 16px;
 font-size: 24px;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
 -moz-border-radius: 2px;
 border-radius: 2px;
}

h1 {
 font-weight: 900;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 80px;
 margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<header style="background QUE SE MODIFICA"> <!-- Inicio HEADER -->
<div id="sticky">
 <h1>Título que se modifica</h1>
 <a class="btn" href="LINK QUE SE MODIFICA">Ver Ahora</a>
 <a class="btn" href="LINK QUE SE MODIFICA">+ Favoritos</a>
</div>
</header> <!-- Fin HEADER -->
```

y aquí les dejo el código de mi ***INDEX.php*** donde se encontraría el botón que accionaría el cambio..

```html
<h3>Recomendados</h3>
<ul id="carousel"><!-- Inicio CAROUSEL -->
<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' =>  6, // we need only the latest post, so get that post only
    'cat' => '1', // Use the category id, can also replace with category_name which uses category slug
    //'category_name' => 'SLUG OF FOO CATEGORY,
);
$q = new WP_Query( $args);

if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    $q->the_post();        
        //Your template tags and markup like:
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $recent['ID'], array( 276, 150), array( 'class' => 'alignleft' ) ) .'</a></li> ';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
</ul><!-- Fin CAROUSEL -->
```

Mayormente mi problema es que no está precisamente el contenido ahí, es decir, hace una llamada para traer las últimas 6 publicaciones de cierta categoría. Entonces, no sabría como resolver para realizar el cambio al hacer CLICK.

Estuve investigando varios scripts, pero no encuentro la manera..
Uno de ellos es http://jsfiddle.net/LUKGt/5/

Comment: [Stack Snippet](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3292/65) sólo debe usarse con código HTML, CSS y JavaScript no con PHP.

Answer (score 1):

le voy ayudar con su poblemas, lo mas faci seria utilizar jquey con esta accion usted puede añadir, reeplazar y eliminar contenido en los div

aqui le dejo el un codigo funcionado, ya el resto le toca a usted mismo que lo adapte

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).on('click','#massmodal', function() {

            $(carousel).append("<br>Hello world!<br>como esta tu<br>");

        });
$(document).on('click','#reeplamodal', function() {
            $(carousel).replaceWith("<ul id='carousel'>Hello world!<br>como esta tu<br></ul>");

            //para eliminar utilizar
            //$(carousel).remove();

        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>hola como esta tu
<ul id="carousel">hola como esta tu</ul>
</div>

<button id="massmodal">Añadir</button>
<button id="reeplamodal">replazar</button>

</body>
</html>
```